# Create an automator/applescript service that opens a file in an external program

Tags: macos, mac, applescript, automator

### Just wondering about some automator/applescript help.

Basically: I download a MP3 file from an artist ([for example](https://soundcloud.com/wearegta/gta-cake))

It is saved to my Downloads folder.

From there, I want to open it automatically in an external MP3 tag editor [such as this one](http://kid3.sourceforge.net).

Then, I will edit the tags and save the file.

When the file is saved, I want to have the newly edited MP3 moved to a folder (my iTunes "Add Automatically" folder, `Macintosh HD ▸ Users ▸ Steve ▸ Music ▸ iTunes ▸ iTunes Media ▸ Add Automatically to iTunes`.

Currently I have an Automator workflow that `Filter Finder Items` and `Move Finder Items` the mp3 into the iTunes folder, but I want to be able to edit the tags first. [Here is a picture of what I have set up right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrhmZ.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use "Open Finder items" and choose a program from the drop-down list.
An example from one of my workflows:

[image: action example]

Comment: But can the file then be moved into a folder AFTER it is saved with an external IDE tag editor?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I figured it out on my own.

I used [ID3 Editor](http://www.pa-software.com/id3editor/) instead of kid3.

My workflow consists of:

Filter items (Music)

Open in ID3 editor

Ask for confirmation ("click ok if you are ready")

Move finder files

Thanks for assistance Rilakkuma!